React pass key index as prop to component
I'm trying to resolve the Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. error but I'm receiving some unexpected results.
This works (no warning):
Home.tsx
{cars?.map((car, index) => (
    <Col key={index}>
        <CarCard car={car} />
    </Col>
))}

CardCard.tsx
interface IProps {
    car: CarSummary
}

export default function CarCard({ car }: IProps) {
    return (
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={car.image} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{car.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                        {car.text}
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Details</Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
    )
}

But if I move the surrounding <Col key={index}></Col> to the CarCard.tsx component and try to pass the index as a prop, I get the Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. warning.
Home.tsx
{cars?.map((car, index) => (
    <CarCard car={car} index={index} />
))}

CarCard.tsx
interface IProps {
    car: CarSummary,
    index: number
}

export default function CarCard({ car, index }: IProps) {
    return (
        <Col key={index}>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={car.image} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{car.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                        {car.text}
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Details</Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </Col>
    )
}

What am I doing wrong that I'm getting a error when I try to pass the index as a prop?

You should keep key in Home.tsx. The key need to be provided to the component that’s straight after map. Also it’s not recommended to use index as key

React needs that key to be at the top JSX element being iterated, not somewhere in its child elements.  For example:
{cars?.map((car, index) => (
  <CarCard car={car} key={index} />
))}

You can also pass it as a prop if the child elements need it for something:
{cars?.map((car, index) => (
  <CarCard car={car} key={index} index={index} />
))}

But that's separate from React's top-level key.

Note also that the array index is kind of a "last resort" key.  It's better to use a meaningful unique identifier of some kind.  For example, if car has an id value:
{cars?.map((car) => (
  <CarCard car={car} key={car.id} />
))}

In many cases (e.g. a static display of <li> elements with no interaction) it's not a big deal... until it is.  If the collection were to be editable/filterable/sortable/etc. then using the array index can cause otherwise difficult-to-debug bugs.

I guess I didn't realize that the key needed to be at the top level. Thanks for the explanation.
